# Homework on basic inequalities.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $a_j$ be a sequence of positive reals. Show that
(a) $\left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\right)^\theta \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j^\theta$ for any $0\le\theta\le1$.
(b) $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j^\theta \le \left(\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\right)^\theta $ for any $1\le\theta<\infty$.
(c) $\left(\sum_{j=1}^N a_j\right)^\theta \le N^{\theta-1} \sum_{j=1}^N a_j^\theta$, when $1\le\theta<\infty$.
(d) $\sum_{j=1}^N a_j^\theta \le \sum_{j=1}^N N^{1-\theta} \left(\sum_{j=1}^N\right)^\theta$, when $0\le\theta\le1$.

I think it is about the convex/concave function but I don't have an explicit idea.

Comment: **Hint:** Jensen's inequality.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @paradox I have edited your post using LaTeX syntax for mathematics. This should improve readability and it is also more permanent solution than using images. Please, check whether I have not changed something in your question by mistake. You can also remove the picture now, if you wish.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a) note that $(x+y)^{p}\le x^{p}+y^{p}$ when $0<p<1$ and $x,y\ge0$. Then:

$(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k})^{\theta}\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{\theta}\le\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}^{\theta}$

where $n$ was arbitrary. To prove the first inequality mentioned notice that for $y=0$ it is clear and it suffices to show the case when $y=1$ since if it is true in this case then: $$(x+y)^{p}=y^{p}(\frac{x}{y}+1)^{p}\le y^{p}((\frac{x}{y})^{p}+1)=x^{p}+y^{p}$$ Then simply show that the function $f(x)=(x+1)^{p}-x^{p}$ is decreasing on the non-negative reals. For $(b)$ note that $x^{p}+y^{p}\le(x+y)^{p}$ when $p\ge1$ and $x,y\ge0$ and we proceed by a similar proof as in (a). (c) follows from Holder's inequality:

$\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{k}\le(\sum_{k=1}^{N}1)^{\frac{\theta-1}{\theta}}(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{k}^{\theta})^{\frac{1}{\theta}}=(N^{\theta-1}\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{k}^{\theta})^{\frac{1}{\theta}}$

and (d) follows from the reverse Holder's inequality:

$\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{k}\ge(\sum_{k=1}^{N}1)^{\frac{1}{\theta}(\theta-1)}(\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{k}^{\theta})^{\frac{1}{\theta}}=(N^{\theta-1}\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_{k}^{\theta})^{\frac{1}{\theta}}$

Comment: thanks for your answers.but I still have a question.if f(x) decrease on non-negative,why $f(x)\le 1$?

Comment: One more thing.reversed Holder's inequality is derived from the reversed Young inequality.There is a geometry explanation to the Young inequality.I wonder there is also one in the reversed version?

Comment: If you evaluate $f$ at $x=0$ you get $1$ and we know that it is decreasing. I'm afraid that I'm not aware of any geometric interpretation of the reverse young's inequality. But given that it is proven by means of an application of young's inequality I would guess that any geometric interpretation would follow closely to the one for Young's inequality.